# Recorded voice can’t hear clearly

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

I'm making a karaoke application.If the headphones aren't plugged in, my app works fine. (my voice and background music record together). It is successful.So that, I merge background music and voice recorded when headphone is plugged in… If i merge two songs i hear both sound clearly.But the issue is if i recorded my voice and music i can hear voice my voice very low.

```
func mixAudio()
{
    let currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    compositionAudioTrack.preferredVolume = 0.8
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset.init(URL: soundFileURL, options: nil)
    print("\(avAsset)")
    var tracks = avAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let clipAudioTrack = tracks[0]
    do {
        try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration), ofTrack: clipAudioTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
    let compositionAudioTrack1 = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    compositionAudioTrack.preferredVolume = 0.8

    let avAsset1 = AVURLAsset.init(URL: soundFileURL1)
    print(avAsset1)


    var tracks1 = avAsset1.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let clipAudioTrack1 = tracks1[0]
    do {
        try compositionAudioTrack1.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset1.duration), ofTrack: clipAudioTrack1, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let CachesDirectory = paths[0]
    let strOutputFilePath = CachesDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/newone.mov")
    print(" strOutputFilePath is \n \(strOutputFilePath)")

    let requiredOutputPath = CachesDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/newone.m4a")
    print(" requiredOutputPath is \n \(requiredOutputPath)")

    soundFile1 = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(requiredOutputPath)
    print(" OUtput path is \n \(soundFile1)")
    do {

        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(soundFile1)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    exporter!.outputURL = soundFile1
    exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A

    exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler
        {() -> Void in
            print(" OUtput path is \n \(requiredOutputPath)")
            print("export complete: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - currentTime)")

    do
    {
        print(self.soundFile1)
        print(" OUtput path is \n \(requiredOutputPath)")


        self.wasteplayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: self.soundFile1)
        self.wasteplayer.numberOfLoops = 0
        self.wasteplayer.play()


    }

    catch _ {
    }

    }
```

Comment: try to set `self.wasteplayer.volume = 4.0f;` or greater than that.

Comment: i tried this, But it increase the audio sound not the voice

Comment: Use the following settings for recording `let recordSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVSampleRateKey : 16000.0,
        ]` In this case I have used .m4a format.